# Win32 C++ ListView WM_CONTEXTMENU Issue

Tags: c, listview, winapi, win32gui

I have a ListView with which I'd like to use a context menu that changes depending on selection. I'm making sure that I'm first able to display a menu when the right mouse button has been released (as per normal context menu behaviour).

In my ListView `WNDPROC` I'm using `WM_CONTEXTMENU` to display the context menu. The menu however is displayed at the location the cursor began the selection, not at the end.

From the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-contextmenu):

> DefWindowProc generates the WM_CONTEXTMENU message when it processes the WM_RBUTTONUP or WM_NCRBUTTONUP message or when the user types SHIFT+F10. The WM_CONTEXTMENU message is also generated when the user presses and releases the VK_APPS key.

When I inspect the call stack, with a breakpoint in `WM_CONTEXTMENU`, I see that the message sent prior to `WM_CONTEXTMENU` was `0x0204` or `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` containing the coordinates of the cursor at this time. This probably explains the menu location issue, but why would this be happening?

When I hold the RMB down outside of the ListView and release it inside, the context menu still appears and I can see from the call stack that the last message was `0x0205` or `WM_RBUTTONUP`.

Not sure whether I have something wrong in my code, or I'm not understanding something. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `0x0205` is `WM_RBUTTONUP`.  `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` is `0x0204`

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I'll fix that now.

Comment: When processing `WM_CONTEXTMENU`, does `GetMessagePos()` give you the correct coordinates you are looking for?

Comment: It does. I wonder if there's a `WM_RBUTTONUP` coming in after the `WM_CONTEXTMENU` which results in `GetMessagePos()` picking up the mouse coordinates from that?

Comment: What about the coordinates reported by `WM_CONTEXTMENU` itself?

Comment: The coordinates from the `LPARAM` are the ones contained within the `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than relying on the `WM_RBUTTON(DOWN|UP)` messages to determine the mouse coordinates, the `WM_CONTEXTMENU`'s own `lParam` gives you the mouse's screen coordinates of the message that generated the `WM_CONTEXTMENU`.  If those coordinates are not what you are expecting, you can use `GetMessagePos()` instead, which will report the screen coordinates at the time `WM_CONTEXTMENU` was generated.  Either way, you can then convert the screen coordinates into ListView client coordinates using `ScreenToClient()` or `MapWindowPoints()`.

Just be sure you also handle the case where the popup menu is being invoked by the user via keyboard input rather than mouse click. In that case, the `lParam` of `WM_CONTEXTMENU` will carry the screen coordinates `[x=-1,y=-1]`, and you can query the ListView for the position of its selected item(s) using `LVM_GETITEMPOSITION` or `LVM_GETITEMRECT` as needed, then convert that position to screen coordinates using `ClientToScreen()` or `MapWindowPoints()`, and then display the popup menu at that screen location.

Comment: Thanks for this. Interestingly, ListViews in MMC seem to have the same issue I was having, whereas if you RMB box select elements in Windows Explorer and release the RMB outside of the control, it will not show a context menu but rather just select the items.

Comment: I have the same issue with ListBox.  Upon processing `WM_RBUTTONDOWN`, `lParam` converted to screen coords with `ClientToScreen()` gives the wrong value.  As advised by Remy, `GetMessagePos()` returns the correct value.  What a pain.  Yet another Win32 API bug (or undocumented behaviour)!

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Your WinAPI answers are the best on SO, I've learned so much about windows programing just by stopping by on your solutions.